# Can I prevent Windows 7 to switch to 16 bit color when I play a Bluray?

Tags: windows-7, blu-ray

I would like to know if there's any way to prevent Windows 7 to switch to 16 bit color mode when I play a bluray .. No matter which player I use, whenever I play a bluray on Windows 7, the color mode always switches to 16 bit and this reduces the video quality .. I would like to avoid this if possible ..

Comment: why is this tagged gaming?

Comment: Maybe update your graphic card driver, see if it solves it.